# Mongo queries to search all the collections of a database (Mongo/PyMongo)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have been stuck on how to query `db` which the common data structure of every document looks as:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e0983863bcf0dab51f2872b"
    },
    "word": "never",  // get the `word` value for each of below queries
    "wordset_id": "a42b50e85e",
    "meanings": [{
        "id": "1f1bca9d9f",
        "def": "not ever",
        "speech_part": "adverb",
        "synonyms": ["ne'er"]
    }, {
        "id": "d35f973ed0",
        "def": "not at all",
        "speech_part": "adverb"
    }]
}
```

1) query to get all the `word`for `speech_part`: "adverb"   (eg: never,....) //

2)query to get all the `word` for: `word` length of `6` and  `speech_part`: "adverb"

I have learnt from SO that ,to search whole collections first i have to retrieve all collections in the database , but how to write a query is where i stuck

Comment: Querying docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({"meanings.speech_part":"adverb"},{"_id":0, "word":1})
```

To get array of all word of a specific speech_part above is the query.

First part of the query is filter predicate like in your scenario matching `speach_part`.if your matching column were not inside another object or a object inside a array, you could just write `{column_name: "something"}`.
as `speech_part` is inside an object which is inside an array, you have to write `{"parentClumn.key":"something"}`, in your case `{"meanings.speech_part":"adverb"}`.

where second part of the query is projection where you define which columns you want in your result. so to get only word column values you do `{word:1}`, to have more column you do `{word:1, etc:1}`. While mongodb project `_id` by default, so to remove `_id` from result you have to explicitly set `{_id:0}`

```
    db.collection.find({
          "meanings.speech_part":"adverb", 
          "$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$word" }, 6 ] }
    },{"_id":0, "word":1})
```

To get array of all word of a specific speech_part with length greater than 6. This one is a bit complex query. You can look up $`expr` documentation. In `$expr` you can run function on your column and match the result. In your case `strLenCP` is calculating the length of your `word` column value and then checking, is it greater then 6 by `$gt` comparison operator

Comment: so for multiple conditions I can just put a comma and condition ?

Comment: yes. like {word: "something", "wordset_id":"something"}

Comment: Hey shahin, how to query such that , length = 6, speech_part= noun and word containing ac (anywhere) in it ?

Answer (score 1):

You may try below query to get the matching rows. You will have to try the same with pymongo.

```
db.getCollection('test-collection').find(
    {
        'meanings.speech_part': 'adverb'
    },
    {
        _id: 0,
        word: 1
    }
);
```

Read about the projections in mongodb here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results

Comment: why to have _id= 0, word: 1 ? any reason for that , could you explain in brief

Comment: the first part of the find query above is where you give your condition to match. And, the 2nd is where you specify which fields you want to get - e.g. when you don't want '_id' or any other field you say '0' and value '1' to get the fields you want. The link I provided with answer will be useful for you to go through.

Comment: sure mate ,thanks for guiding link I would definitely go through the link